# how can i use next and previse button in pagination in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

how can i use next and previse button in pagination in react?
thanks for answer
my App component:
i get post api from jsonholder
i want when clicked in next button, currentPage changed and in go to next  until it go to last page( here page 10)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';
import Paginations from './components/paginations/Paginations';
import PostManager from './components/posts/PostManager';


function App() {
  /////////states:
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [postPerPage, setPostPerPage] = useState(10)
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

  const lastOfIndex = currentPage * postPerPage  ////// first index in current page
  const firstOfIndex = lastOfIndex - postPerPage ///// last index in current page
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(firstOfIndex, lastOfIndex)  ///////// posts in current pages
  ////////// conect to api in use effect :
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCourse = async () => {

      setLoading(true)
      console.log(loading)
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      setPosts(data);  ////get data and set it in posts
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(loading)

    }
    fetchCourse();
  }, [])
  /////////////onclick on paginats//////////

  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);


  console.log(posts)
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>.....loading.......</h2>
  }
  return (
    <div className="App container">

      {/* ////// post manager manage posts  */}
      <PostManager
        posts={currentPosts}

      />

      {/* nav paginate: */}
      <Paginations
        currentPage={currentPage}
        setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
        postsLength={posts.length}
        postPerPage={postPerPage}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

pagination components:
(here posts paginat)

```
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const Paginations = ({setCurrentPage,currentPage, postsLength, postPerPage,paginate }) => {
     let pageNumber = []
     for (let i = 1; i <=  Math.ceil(postsLength / postPerPage); i++) {
          pageNumber.push(i)
     }
     let style =null
     const ttst =( number) =>{
          paginate(number);
           style ="active"
       console.log(style)    
     }
     console.log(currentPage)
     console.log(pageNumber)
          return (
               <Fragment>
{/* {currentPage === pageNumber ? 'active' : ''} */}
                    <div className="center">
                         <ul className="pagination">
                              <li><a>«</a></li>
                              {/* <li><a>1</a></li>
                              <li><a className="active">2</a></li> */}
                              {pageNumber.map(number =>(
                                    <li ><a className={currentPage === number ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => paginate(number)}>{number}</a></li>
                              ))}
                              <li><a onClick={() =>{setCurrentPage(currentPage ++)}}>»</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>



               </Fragment>
          );
     }

     export default Paginations;
```

i try it a lot but i cant soled it
can you help me?